# Converting XML to JSON in Node JS

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, mongodb

There are some similar topics on Stack Overflow but I can't find any which actually explain how to do it.

I have an API which returns data as `XML`. I want to convert this to `JSON` as I'm storing it in `MongoDB`.

```
<cj-api>
    <products total-matched="231746" records-returned="999" page-number="1">
        <product>
            <ad-id>10648829</ad-id>
            <advertiser-id>2618386</advertiser-id>
            <advertiser-name>Acne Jeans UK</advertiser-name>
            <advertiser-category>New Arrivals</advertiser-category>
            <buy-url>http://www.tkqlhce.com/click-7227532-10648829?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.acnestudios.com%2Fpop-cord-white.html&cjsku=30X133-151</buy-url>
            <catalog-id>cjo:939</catalog-id>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            <description>Pop Cord White.</description>
            <image-url>http://c893323.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/catalog/product/cache/25/thumbnail/300x300/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/0/30X133-151_A_57419.jpg</image-url>
            <in-stock>true</in-stock>
            <isbn/>
            <manufacturer-name>Acne Studios</manufacturer-name>
            <manufacturer-sku/>
            <name>Pop Cord White</name>
            <price>200.0</price>
            <retail-price/>
            <sale-price/>
            <sku>30X133-151</sku>
            <upc/>
        </product>
        <product>
            <ad-id>10648829</ad-id>
            <advertiser-id>2618386</advertiser-id>
            <advertiser-name>Acne Jeans UK</advertiser-name>
            <advertiser-category>Jeans</advertiser-category>
            <buy-url>http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-7227532-10648829?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.acnestudios.com%2Fflex-black.html&cjsku=30H126-129</buy-url>
            <catalog-id>cjo:939</catalog-id>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            <description>Acne Flex Black jeans are narrow, tight fitting jeans with a comfortable mid rise waist.<ul>
                <li>Worn in black blue wash</li>
                <li>Classic five pocket styling</li>
                <li>Zippered fly front closure</li>
                <li>Secures at the waist with bachelor button</li>
                <li>Acne embossed rivets</li>
                </ul>.</description>
                <image-url>http://c893323.r23.cf3.rackcdn.com/catalog/product/cache/25/thumbnail/300x300/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/0/30H126-129_A_18.jpg</image-url>
                <in-stock>true</in-stock>
                <isbn/>
                <manufacturer-name>Acne Studios</manufacturer-name>
                <manufacturer-sku/>
                <name>Flex Black</name>
                <price>170.0</price>
                <retail-price/>
                <sale-price/>
                <sku>30H126-129</sku>
                <upc/>
            </product>     
    </products>
</cj-api>
```

***(let's pretend there are only 2 products - in actuality there are 231,746!)***

In Node, I'm using `request` to gather this XML and store it in a variable, called `body`. I'm using `libxmljs`, like so:

```
    var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXmlString(body);
    var product = xmlDoc.get('//product'); <!-- very unsure whether I'm using this correctly
```

The issue is that I have absolutely no idea how to work with this data, and the [libxmljs docs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki) are really unhelpful in this regard. I'd like to do something equivalent to jQuery's:

```
$('product').each(function(){
    var obj = {
        advertiser-name: $(this).find('advertiser-name'),
        buy-url: $(this).find('buy-url'),
        ... etc etc etc
})
```

How can I do this using `libxmljs` / another library so that I can work with the data more easily?

Answer (score 4):

About using `libxmljs`:

- You need to use `xmlDoc.find('//product')` instead of `get`, because `get` returns only first element for specific XPath (`//product` is a [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)). You can find all other methods for document object on [wiki](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Document)
- Method `find` returns array of [elements](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/Element), so equivalent to your jQuery example will be:

  ```
  var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXmlString(xml);

  var products = xmlDoc.find('//product');
  for (var index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
    var obj = {
      "advertiser-name": products[index].get('advertiser-name').text()
    };

    // ...
  }
  ```

  In this example for each element I use method `get` (because I know that only one child has this name) to get child element and after this just ask `text` value of this element.

At second I'd like to recommend you `xml2js` module ([github](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js)), which can convert xml to JSON object. For this you just need to use `parseString` function with two parameters `xml` string and callback  `function (err, result) { ... }`, where result will be JSON representation of this xml.

Because you also mentioned that each xml can have > 200,000 products - you need to be aware about performance of these libraries. It seems to me that both of them will load whole XML in memory. If you need to execute this script just once or maybe once a day (or hour) - I guess it can be fine to use it as is. If you will need to improve performance you should take a look on [SaxPushParser](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/wiki/SaxPushParser) interface from `libxmljs` library.